# Reference is not a tree error while deploying with capistrano and git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I been able to do capistrano deploys for a while for a certain app but recently I cannot deploy anymore git whines: "fatal: reference is not a tree: a84...". I don't know what did I do, I don't think I changed the deploy file, I am not using git submodules, and the hex reference correspond to the latest commit I do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but changing the domain from an ip address to my domain solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to ensure that you actually pushed this branch to your remote repository, not just committed it.

Also check that capistrano is looking at the same branch as you expect in your config/deploy.rb file

```
set :branch, "master"
```

Comment: Thanks! You hit it right on the head, silly me I forgot to push to the remote repo :)